# Mara systems border firewall with pfSense

Tags: networking, firewall, router, pfsense

I just bought a used Mara systems Border firewall with pfSense installed on it. I want to reset it or reinstall pfSense because I cant reach the WebGUI or anything. Does anyone know how to go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do that from the console, if the device has a console. That's the standard way of doing that in pfSense.